# How to return list of integer as JSON objects in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning ASP.Net MVC5. And I have a case where I need to return a JSON result. Currently, I have list of integer. But I want to return it as json objects. Below is what I have

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult hello()
    {
        var x = SMS_DAL._DalColl.lstOfID;
        return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Observation: the variable `x` contains `list of integer`. And I want to return it as JSON objects. Below is how `x` looks like during VS debugging.

```
X    Count = 3
  [0]   -1
  [1]    2134....
  [2]    28463
```

I have studied JSON and it contains of key value pair like below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
}
```

So, I ran the controller action and checked the values in Advanced Rest Client.

[image]

We can clearly see the value I got are like below

```
[Array[3]

0: -1

1: 2134...

2: 2843

]
```

Where are the "double quotes" and where are the "curly braces" representing key and values. Why don't I see them. The result that I am getting are they actually JSON? please guide me.

Comment: @UnBreakable...It is the way of showing... it is still proper json... just that the tool figures our its it and omits the ""

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking - JSON for "list of integers" would be `[1,2,3]` - but you seem to expect some sort of object with properties...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : You are right. My bad. But can you tell me if someone asks what is the key and value in my case. What should be the answer?

Comment: No idea. Whatever is shown in the post does not look like JSON. Please make sure to look at actual raw response rather than some visualization of the data.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you have into list inside, you can return it as Json.
You code should be looking something like this  :

```
public ActionResult GetNewChatPosts()
{   
    List integerList = new List<int>();
    return Json(list);
}
```

Comment: json is nowhere to be found

Answer (score 0):

Your action is returning an array and that is correct JSON object. Basically, any array is a JSON object if it holds appropriate values - string, number, object, array, boolean or null.
Quick read: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

If you want a key for the array, return an object in JSON format:

```
public class TestAPIController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        return Json(new ArrayResult { Arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } });
    }
}

public class ArrayResult
{
    public int[] Arr { get; set; }
}
```

this will return:

```
{arr: [1,2,3]}
```

Comment: So if someone asks me what is the key and value here. What shall I tell?

Comment: Tell him/her that it returns an array. If someone knows what is JSON, should understand you. Or you can return an object using JSON method (added code sample on my post)

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format. Once you parse it, it's just an object, or, in this case, an array.